# having error when trying to catch values from database and display it in a text view. android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i am having a sqllite database. i am trying to catch values from the database and display it in a text view. i get the following error.

having error in this line

```
TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewres);
```

Full error stack..

```
02-10 21:24:53.986: E/AndroidRuntime(27992): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-10 21:24:53.986: E/AndroidRuntime(27992): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{lk.adspace.jaffnatemples/lk.adspace.jaffnatemples.Db_results}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
02-10 21:24:53.986: E/AndroidRuntime(27992):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
02-10 21:24:53.986: E/AndroidRuntime(27992):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
02-10 21:24:53.986: E/AndroidRuntime(27992):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
02-10 21:24:53.986: E/AndroidRuntime(27992):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
02-10 21:24:53.986: E/AndroidRuntime(27992):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
02-10 21:24:53.986: E/AndroidRuntime(27992):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
02-10 21:24:53.986: E/AndroidRuntime(27992):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
02-10 21:24:53.986: E/AndroidRuntime(27992):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-10 21:24:53.986: E/AndroidRuntime(27992):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-10 21:24:53.986: E/AndroidRuntime(27992):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
02-10 21:24:53.986: E/AndroidRuntime(27992):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
02-10 21:24:53.986: E/AndroidRuntime(27992):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-10 21:24:53.986: E/AndroidRuntime(27992): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
02-10 21:24:53.986: E/AndroidRuntime(27992):    at lk.adspace.jaffnatemples.Db_results.onCreate(Db_results.java:52)
02-10 21:24:53.986: E/AndroidRuntime(27992):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
02-10 21:24:53.986: E/AndroidRuntime(27992):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
02-10 21:24:53.986: E/AndroidRuntime(27992):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
02-10 21:24:53.986: E/AndroidRuntime(27992):    ... 11 more
```

**DB handler class..**

```
    package lk.adspace.jaffnatemples;



    import java.util.ArrayList;


    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class Dbhandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper  {


        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

        // Database Name
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "jaffnatempletest";

        // Temple table name
        private static final String TABLE_TEMPLE = "templ";


        // Contacts Table Columns names
        private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
        private static final String KEY_TMPNAME = "temple_name";
        private static final String KEY_TMPTYPE = "temple_type";
        private static final String KEY_LATITUDE = "latitude";
        private static final String KEY_LONGITUDE = "longitude";
        private static final String KEY_IMGNAME = "image_name";
        private static final String KEY_YEARBUILD = "year_build";
        private static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
        private static final String KEY_CITY = "city";
        private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
        private static final String KEY_WEB = "website";
        private static final String KEY_TEL1 = "telephone1";
        private static final String KEY_TEL2 = "telephone2";
        private static final String KEY_DESCRI = "Description";
        private final ArrayList<kovil> temple_list = new ArrayList<kovil>();


        public Dbhandler (Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }



        // Creating Tables
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TEMPLE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TEMPLE + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL," + KEY_TMPNAME + " TEXT," + KEY_TMPTYPE + " TEXT," + KEY_LATITUDE + " TEXT," + KEY_LONGITUDE + " TEXT," + KEY_IMGNAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_YEARBUILD + " TEXT," + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT," + KEY_CITY + " TEXT," + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT," + KEY_WEB + " TEXT," + KEY_TEL1 + " TEXT," + KEY_TEL2 + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_DESCRI + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TEMPLE_TABLE);
        }


        // Upgrading database
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TEMPLE);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
        }



        // Adding new temple
        public void Add_Temple(kovil Kovil) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_TMPNAME, Kovil.gettemplename()); 
        values.put(KEY_TMPTYPE, Kovil.gettempletype()); 
        values.put(KEY_LATITUDE, Kovil.getlatitude()); 
        values.put(KEY_LONGITUDE, Kovil.getlongitude()); 
        values.put(KEY_IMGNAME, Kovil.getimage_name()); 
        values.put(KEY_YEARBUILD, Kovil.getyear_build()); 
        values.put(KEY_ADDRESS, Kovil.getaddress()); 
        values.put(KEY_CITY, Kovil.getcity()); 
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, Kovil.getemail()); 
        values.put(KEY_WEB, Kovil.getwebsite()); 
        values.put(KEY_TEL1, Kovil.gettelephone1()); 
        values.put(KEY_TEL2, Kovil.gettelephone2());
        values.put(KEY_DESCRI, Kovil.getDescription());

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_TEMPLE, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
        }






        // Getting single contact
        kovil Get_Temple(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_TEMPLE, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                KEY_TMPNAME, KEY_TMPTYPE, KEY_LATITUDE, KEY_LONGITUDE, KEY_IMGNAME, KEY_YEARBUILD, KEY_ADDRESS, KEY_CITY, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_WEB, KEY_TEL1, KEY_TEL2, KEY_DESCRI }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        kovil Kovil = new kovil(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8), cursor.getString(9), cursor.getString(10), cursor.getString(11), cursor.getString(12), cursor.getString(13));
        // return contact
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        return Kovil;
        }





        // Getting All Contacts
        public ArrayList<kovil> Get_Temple() {
        try {
            temple_list.clear();

            // Select All Query
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TEMPLE;

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            System.out.print("CALLED");
            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                kovil Kovil = new kovil();
                Kovil.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                System.out.print("CALLED"+cursor.getString(0));
                Kovil.settemplename(cursor.getString(1)); 
                Kovil.settempletype(cursor.getString(2)); 
                Kovil.setlatitude(cursor.getString(3)); 
                Kovil.setlongitude(cursor.getString(4)); 
                Kovil.setimage_name(cursor.getString(5)); 
                Kovil.setyear_build(cursor.getString(6)); 
                Kovil.setaddress(cursor.getString(7)); 
                Kovil.setcity(cursor.getString(8)); 
                Kovil.setemail(cursor.getString(9)); 
                Kovil.setwebsite(cursor.getString(10)); 
                Kovil.settelephone1(cursor.getString(11)); 
                Kovil.settelephone2(cursor.getString(12));
                Kovil.setDescription(cursor.getString(13));



                // Adding contact to list
                temple_list.add(Kovil);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            // return contact list
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
            return temple_list;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("all_temples", "" + e);
        }

        return temple_list;
        }

        public String collect(){

            SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
            String result="";
            String []column =new String[]{KEY_ID,KEY_TMPNAME,KEY_TMPTYPE,KEY_LATITUDE,KEY_LONGITUDE,KEY_IMGNAME,KEY_YEARBUILD,KEY_ADDRESS,KEY_CITY,KEY_EMAIL,KEY_WEB,KEY_TEL1,KEY_TEL2,KEY_DESCRI};
            Cursor c=ourDatabase.query("templ", column, null, null, null, null,null, null);
            //Cursor c=ourDatabase.query(
            c.moveToFirst();
            int iKEY_ID = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID);
            int iKEY_TMPNAME= c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TMPNAME);
            int iKEY_TMPTYPE= c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TMPTYPE);
            for (c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
                //for (int x=0;x<5;x++){
            result = result+c.getString(iKEY_ID)+"  "+c.getString(iKEY_TMPNAME)+" \t\t\t\t"+c.getString(iKEY_TMPTYPE)+" \n";
            }
            return result;

        }


        // Getting contacts Count
        public int Get_Total_Temple() {
            String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_TEMPLE;
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
            int count = cursor.getCount();
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
            return count;
        }


    }
```

**My main display class(Db_results.java)**

```
    package lk.adspace.jaffnatemples;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.ContactsContract.Data;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Db_results<LayoutInfalter> extends Activity {



        Temple_Adapter tAdapter;

        ArrayList<kovil> temple_data = new ArrayList<kovil>();
        ListView temple_listview;
        Dbhandler dbhand = new Dbhandler(this); 



                    @Override
                    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        setContentView(R.layout.display_db_result);

                        temple_listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                        kovil insertData = new kovil("temple_name", "temple_type", "latitude",  "longitude", "image_name", "year_build", "address", 
                                "city", "email", "website", "telephone1", "telephone2",  "Description");
                            Dbhandler dbhand = new Dbhandler(this); 
                            dbhand .Add_Temple(insertData );


                            kovil insertData2 = new kovil("temple_name2", "temple_type2", "latitude2",  "longitude2", "image_name2", "year_build2", "address2", 
                                    "city2", "email2", "website2", "telephone12", "telephone22",  "Description2");

                                dbhand .Add_Temple(insertData2 );

                              //  int count =dbhand .Get_Total_Temple();

                            // TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.count);

                                TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewres);

                             //String c=collect();
                                result.setText(dbhand.collect());



                             // i want to display all the values in a list over here.
                             System.out.print("CALLING View_all_temples");
                        //View_all_temples();


                    }



                    public void View_all_temples(){

                        System.out.print("iNTO View_all_temples STAGE 1");
                        //temple_data.clear();

                        ArrayList<kovil> temple_array_from_db = dbhand.Get_Temple();
                        System.out.print("CALLED View_all_temples");
                        for (int i = 0; i < temple_array_from_db.size(); i++) {

                            System.out.print("INTO LOOP");

                            int tidno = temple_array_from_db.get(i).getID();
                            String tempname = temple_array_from_db.get(i).gettemplename();
                            String city = temple_array_from_db.get(i).getcity();
                            String telphon = temple_array_from_db.get(i).gettelephone1();
                            kovil kov = new kovil();
                            kov.setID(tidno);
                            kov.settemplename(tempname);
                            kov.setcity(city);
                            kov.settelephone1(telphon);

                            temple_data.add(kov);


                        }
                        dbhand.close();
                        //tAdapter = new Temple_Adapter(Db_results.this, R.layout.display_db_result,temple_data);
                        //tAdapter = new Temple_Adapter(Db_results.this, R.layout.display_db_result);
                        //temple_listview.setAdapter(tAdapter);
                        tAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                    }



                    public class Temple_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<kovil> {

                        Activity activity;
                        int layoutResourceId;
                        kovil user;
                        LayoutInfalter mInfalter;    
                        ArrayList<kovil> data = new ArrayList<kovil>();
                        ViewHolder holder; 
                        public Temple_Adapter(Context act,
                                int layoutResourceId,  ArrayList<kovil> data) {
                        super(act,layoutResourceId,data);
                        tAdapter = new Temple_Adapter(Db_results.this, R.layout.display_db_result,temple_data);
                        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
                        this.activity = (Activity) act;
                        this.data = data;

                        }



                        @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "null" })
                        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 


                                    if (convertView == null) { 
                                        LayoutInflater mInflater = null;
                                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.display_db_result,parent, false);
                                        holder = new ViewHolder(); 
                                        holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                                        convertView.setTag(holder);  // set tag on view
                                   } else { 
                                       holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                                   } 

                                   holder.tv.setText((CharSequence) data.get(position).temple_name);
                                   return convertView; 
                        }
                          public class ViewHolder
                           {
                                TextView tv;
                           }



                    }


                    @Override
                    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                        return true;
                    }

                }
```

**Manifest file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="lk.adspace.jaffnatemples"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

        <permission android:name="lk.adspace.jaffnatemples.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
                    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

        <uses-permission android:name="lk.adspace.jaffnatemples.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

        <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true"/>




        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="lk.adspace.jaffnatemples.Main"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".Search"/>
            <activity
                android:name="lk.adspace.jaffnatemples.Search_result"
                android:label="@string/app_name" />

            <activity android:name="lk.adspace.jaffnatemples.Map_view"
                android:label="@string/app_name" />


            <activity android:name="lk.adspace.jaffnatemples.Db_results"
                android:label="@string/app_name" />


            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                        android:value="AIzaSyBbouC2RTAM-AC2Vh6MYFF2JrzFGDg" />
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

**Display Db_result.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/textviewres"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

        </ListView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textviewres"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**New error Stack**

```
02-10 21:45:31.473: E/AndroidRuntime(31356): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-10 21:45:31.473: E/AndroidRuntime(31356): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{lk.adspace.jaffnatemples/lk.adspace.jaffnatemples.Db_results}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView
02-10 21:45:31.473: E/AndroidRuntime(31356):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
02-10 21:45:31.473: E/AndroidRuntime(31356):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
02-10 21:45:31.473: E/AndroidRuntime(31356):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
02-10 21:45:31.473: E/AndroidRuntime(31356):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
02-10 21:45:31.473: E/AndroidRuntime(31356):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
02-10 21:45:31.473: E/AndroidRuntime(31356):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
02-10 21:45:31.473: E/AndroidRuntime(31356):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
02-10 21:45:31.473: E/AndroidRuntime(31356):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-10 21:45:31.473: E/AndroidRuntime(31356):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-10 21:45:31.473: E/AndroidRuntime(31356):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
02-10 21:45:31.473: E/AndroidRuntime(31356):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
02-10 21:45:31.473: E/AndroidRuntime(31356):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-10 21:45:31.473: E/AndroidRuntime(31356): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView
02-10 21:45:31.473: E/AndroidRuntime(31356):    at lk.adspace.jaffnatemples.Db_results.onCreate(Db_results.java:36)
02-10 21:45:31.473: E/AndroidRuntime(31356):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
02-10 21:45:31.473: E/AndroidRuntime(31356):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
02-10 21:45:31.473: E/AndroidRuntime(31356):    at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
02-10 21:45:31.473: E/AndroidRuntime(31356):    ... 11 more
```

can someone plz help me to fix this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/textviewres"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

remove ID from this

relative layout and textview both have same id and when you get it in activity it is returning the ralative layout object.

Remove it from relative layout just keep it in textview

Comment: thank you vipul mittal. but after doing that i get the new error. i have added the new error to the question can you plz help to fix that error too..

Comment: try to clean your project and run b'coz id list is a list view and you are casting it right. if you still have problem do post the exact line you are getting this problem

Answer (score 1):

Please post your xml layout or check if this line is correct:

```
TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewres);
```

Is the view with id `textviewres` really `TextView`? According logcat looks like it's `RelativeLayout`

You have duplicated view id. Try to use this layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewres"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i have posted the XML layout. can you please check and let me know the what the error is?..

Comment: Thank you. birdy. but after doing that i get a new error. i have edited the question, can you help me to fix that error plz..

Answer (score 0):

In your code:
 convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.display_db_result,parent, false);
You need to inflate layout which contains only TextView.